# Mover directorio de un ELASTIC SEARCH A OTRO

Tags: elasticsearch

Como saben, el Elastic search genera unos directorios donde la información queda indexada. necesitamos mover ese directorio al ambiente de produccion, tenemos la misma estructura.

mi pregunta es la siguiente.

puedo mover ese directorio del servidor de desarrollo al de producción, sin necesidad de ejecutar nuevamente la indexación. ?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen que contiene P es Producción Y el otro es desarrollo (D)
necesito enviar el data01 y reemplazarlo por el otro

Answer (score 2):

Supongo que si las configuraciones de ambos servidores son idénticas, copiar los archivos debería funcionar. Aunque no estoy seguro que ocurre cuando tenemos un cluster, no obstante esto, la forma de hacerlo según la [documentación](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-migrate-data.html) oficial es alguna de estas

- Indexar los datos desde el "origen", o bien
- Reindexar desde el "destino", o bien
- Crear un snapshot (sería como un dump o backup) en el "origen y luego cargarlo en el "destino"

La última opción entiendo que puede ser la mas conveniente para disaster recovery y/o simplemente para mantener una versión operativa del/los índice/s.

En ese caso, esquemáticamente los pasos serían:

[Registrar un snapshot en "origen"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-register-repository.html)

```
PUT /_snapshot/my_backup
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "una_capeta_del_nodo_master"
  }
}
```

usando `type:fs` (file system) le decimos que es una carpeta.

[Crear un snapshot en "origen"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-take-snapshot.html)

```
PUT /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=true
```

Aqui es donde se pueden hacer varios snapshots, `snapshot_1`, luego `snapshot_2` etc.

[Registramos un snapshot en "destino"](http://PUT%20/_snapshot/my_read_only_url_repository%20%7B%20%20%20%22type%22:%20%22url%22,%20%20%20%22settings%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%22url%22:%20%22file:/mount/backups/my_fs_backup_location%22%20%20%20%7D%20%7D)

```
PUT /_snapshot/my_backup
{
  "type": "url",
  "settings": {
    "url": "file:/mount/backups/my_fs_backup_location"
  }
}
```

usando `type:url` le decimos que es una url. Aqui va la ubicación remota del "origen". Obviamente tiene que ser accesible esa ruta.

[Cargamos el snapshot en "destino"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-restore-snapshot.html)

```
POST /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_restore
```

En este punto indicamos `/_snapshot/<el repositorio registrado>/< el snapshot >/_restore`, en el mismo repositorio podríamos poner varios snapshots.